# Parameterize allowed numeric range or embed in type name?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

From what I have seen up to now, my problem might not be possible to solve within the given constraints, but I'll give it a chance here.

I am trying to write an XSD(1.1)-file matching a pretty simple XML. The problem is the existence of attributes within the XML tags, which forced me to use xs:extension. An example of an element:

```
<xs:element name="Index">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="int1TO10">
                <xs:attribute name="comment" fixed="Attribute in XML Tag"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Whereas the type I created called "int1TO10" looks like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="int1TO10">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This DOES work, the problem being that it is a lot of writing and if you want to change something, you would need to change the reference name to stay consistent as well as the values in the defined type. If this was a small file, this would be doable; but there are quite a few elements here, which can have pretty much any combination of min- and max-Integers. So for each new element someone has to check if a type exists already, or has to create it. This all feels incredibly redundant.

What I'm looking for is a simple solution along the lines of:

```
<xs:element>...
    <xs:extension base="xs:integer" minInclusive="1" maxInclusive="10">
        <xs:attribute name="comment" fixed="Attribute in XML Tag"/>
    </xs:extension>...
</xs:element>
```

Though from what I found, this does not seem to be possible. In [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418421/using-xsextension-xsrestriction-together) for example the accepted answer stated that the way I'm currently doing it is the way to go; though that post is already a little old, so maybe there has been some recent breakthrough that I missed?

The only other option that I can come up with is restructuring the XML file itself, from (current)

```
<Index comment="Attribute in XML Tag">(some value between 1 and 10)</Index>
```

to

```
<Index>
    <value>(some value between 1 and 10)</value>
    <comment>Attribute now in its own tag</comment>
</Index>
```

which would require also quite some work and a change of some other things that work with the XML (scripts etc.), so I would rather avoid that.

So to wrap it up: Is there a way to NOT write a new simpleType for each new Integer combination that my elements can have? Any suggestions are welcome, maybe there is also an entirely different approach or XSD-structure possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you've presented is the way to go.

However, you may ...

- Use a consistent naming scheme like `int_<lower_bound>_to_<upper_bound>` for your range types and autogenerate the matching xsd type declarations from a template using a text processing tool independent from xml schemas.
- Transform the syntax you came up with (`<xs:extension base="xs:integer" minInclusive="1" maxInclusive="10">` using xslt.

**PoC**

**generate (perl)**

Writes a file containing a xml fragment consisting of systematically generated type definitions.

```
use IO::File;
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($dict, $fh_out, $fpath, $instance);
my $tmpl =<<EOTMPL;
<xs:simpleType name="int\${lb}TO\${ub}">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="\${lb}"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="\${ub}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
EOTMPL

my %dict = ( 'lb' => 0,  'ub' => 0 );
$fpath = "<wherever>";
$fh_out = new IO::File ( ">" . $fpath );

for ($dict{lb} = 1; $dict{lb} <= 4; $dict{lb}++ ) {
    for ($dict{ub} = $dict{lb}+1; $dict{ub} <= 4; $dict{ub}++ ) {
        ($instance = $tmpl) =~ s/\$\{([a-z]+)\}/$dict{$1}/g;
        print $fh_out "$instance\n";
    }
}

$fh_out->close;

exit(0);
```

**transform (xslt)**

Transforms all pseudo type specs from the source file into full-fledged `int<m>TO<n>` type declarations. Does not check for duplicate definitions.

```
<?xml-stylesheet version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    t.xslt
    XSD typespec generation
-->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <!--
        Specifying the output
    -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
           Toplevel template:
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:message select="string('main template: start;')"/>
        <mytypes xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </mytypes>
        <xsl:message select="string('main template: end;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
           Type subst
    -->
    <xsl:template match="xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:simpleContent/xs:extension[@base='xs:integer'][@minInclusive][@maxInclusive]">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xsl:attribute name='name' select="concat('int', string(@minInclusive), 'TO', string(@maxInclusive))"/>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive><xsl:attribute name='value' select="number(@minInclusive)"/></xs:minInclusive>
                <xs:maxInclusive><xsl:attribute name='value' select="number(@maxInclusive)"/></xs:maxInclusive>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The first one also just came to my mind over lunch, but I hoped I could get around it. I'll let it sit for a day or so and if nobody presented a different approach, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

### Domain-based Names

First suggestion: Use names that are meaningful to your domain rather than ones that are based on allowed ranges.  For example, use `Score` rather than `int1TO10`; `Degrees` rather than `int1TO360`; `LindenRathanNumber` rather than `int323TO9043`.

Besides following the best practice of using domain-based names, this approach has the nice property of treating the ranges as implementation details.  If in the future the LindenRathan Number maximum changes from 9043 to 9044, it can be changed once in the definition, not everywhere the name itself appears.

### Fully Parameterized Endpoints

Alternative suggestion: If for some unexplained reason it is important to create markup where you wish to expose specific allowable ranges, you could go all the way and have explicit XML attributes for the endpoints:

```
<n min="0" max="10">9</n>
```

Then, using XSD 1.1 assertions, you could constrain the element value to be in range of the given endpoints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1"> 

  <xs:element name="n" type="IntRangeType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="IntRangeType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:int">
        <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:assert test="@max >= @min"/>
        <xs:assert test=". >= @min and . &lt;= @max"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I see your point with the names, but I have the requirement to make the allowed values visible on a quick view on the XSD element, so just using a name, no matter how good, won't cut it, as long as the values aren't in there. Putting all of the value checks into assertions is definitly a possibility, but also separates the element definition and the value range, so it will run into the same problems. Therefor I will probably go collapsars route and stick with int_x_to_y-Names and create all the necessary types with a script. Thanks for the title update btw.